# Viewing a sequence as a function on the space of positive integers

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, functions

I see the following lines in a book :

" Consider a bounded sequence of real or complex numbers $\{\eta_n\}$. Such a sequence $\{\eta_n\}$ defines a function $x(n) = \{\eta_n\}$ defined on the discrete space $S=\{1,2,3,\dots \}$ "

Does it trying to say that because the sequence is bounded it can define the function. Why is that ? consider the sequence of natural numbers.

Comment: It seems you're thinking otherwise. Just because they specify the sequence must be bounded, it doesn't mean they are saying that if the sequence is unbounded, it cannot define a function. Authors usually specify this to work with finite values of $\liminf$ and $\limsup$.

Comment: The boundedness is a requirement they need for something else. Any sequence can be seen as a map $\{ 1,2,3,\ldots \} \to \mathbb{C}$ (or whatever co-domain is appropriate).

Answer (score 1):

Every sequence indexed by positive integers is a function on the space of positive integers. This is usually  taken as the definition of what "sequence" means.

As [Jeppe Stig Nielsen](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/912931/viewing-a-sequence-as-a-function-on-the-space-of-positive-integers#comment1884231_912931) said, it appears that the authors will need the sequence to be bounded at some stage of the proof. So they assumed it to be bounded right at the beginning. This assumption has nothing to do with the sequence being treated as a function.